# How to assign id to a certain item of recyclerView android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have one visible problem in my application. I found api and train to work with retrofit library. Via this api I get the list of jobs from one site and represent them at recyclerview which is based on custom adapter. To this recyclerView I send `jobs: ArrayList<JobModel>` and I created `JobModel` which is my model class. Then in `onBindViewHolder` :

```
val jobModel = jobs[position]
```

and then here is my model class:

```
public class JobModel {
    @SerializedName("company_name")
    @Expose
    private String company_name;

    @SerializedName("lastdate")
    @Expose
    private String lastdate;

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private int id;

    @SerializedName("position")
    @Expose
    private String position;

    @SerializedName("location")
    @Expose
    private String location;

    @SerializedName("job_link")
    @Expose
    private String job_link;

    @SerializedName("seen")
    @Expose
    private boolean seen;

    public JobModel(String company_name, String lastdate, int id, String position, String location, String job_link, boolean seen) {
        this.company_name = company_name;
        this.lastdate = lastdate;
        this.id = id;
        this.position = position;
        this.location = location;
        this.job_link = job_link;
        this.seen = seen;
    }

    public String getCompany_name() {
        return company_name;
    }

    public String getLastdate() {
        return lastdate;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(String position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public String getJob_link() {
        return job_link;
    }
    public boolean isSeen() {
        return seen;
    }
}
```

the problem is that I have to mark clicked job as seen for this I have to send request with id of selected job but I send id of the last visible item of list. I understand why does it happen but I can't imagine how to solve this problem. It happens because I created global variable of id:

```
var jId: Int? = 0
```

and then in `onBindViewHolder` I assign the value to this variable:

```
val jobModel = jobs[position]
jId = jobModel.id
```

and when I click the item list it sends the request with the last visible item at my recyclerView. So I can suggest only one solution - create array which will fill with ids of jobs and then when I will click one of job I will get an item by position and then will send a request.Working with clicks:

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
```

then:

```
override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
        Singleton.clickReq(jId, ctx)
        click.sendData(url, pos!!, jobTitle!!)
    }
```

So, how I can solve my problem?

Comment: What's the purpose of `jId` . as a global variable?

Comment: yes it is a global varible and then I send it at my request and the problem is that value which is assigned to this varibable is similar to id of job at current position

Comment: I tried to make the global array which is filled with ids of jobs, but I don't know how to get the id of clicked job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [**set the jobId as a tag**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setTag(int,%2520java.lang.Object)) in the view while setting the view and then retrieve the jobId of the clicked view.

An example snippet would look like :

```
myTextView.setText(job.getCompanyName());
....
myView.setTag(job.getId());
```

And then when the view is clicked, you can get the corresponding jobId by using

```
clickedJobId = myView.getTag();
```

Comment: where I have to create this tag? as you know I will assign to this `tag` the last visible item of my list or not?

Comment: so I have to add invisible field at my layout where will post this id?

Comment: You set the tag to the view while creating the view and displaying other job details.

Comment: No, you can add a tag/ tags to any view. The tags are not visible and won't effect the UI. You can set the tag to the entire row snippet or a text view in that snippet.

Comment: Have a look at the link to the documentation I shared in my answer.

Comment: it can be a textView? and how I can then send clicked job id? because for me it looks like my method and the last value of id will be the last item of the list

Comment: when a particular job is clicked, you can get the id from the tag of the view and then make your API call.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193773/discussion-between-andrew-goroshko-and-swayam).

Answer (score 0):

```
public class JobListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<JobListAdapter.JobViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<JobModel> mJobList = new ArrayList<>();


    public JobListAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    public void setJobList(ArrayList<JobModel> jobList) {
        mJobList = jobList;
    }

    @Override
    public JobViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_job_list, parent, false);

        JobViewHolder viewHolder = new JobViewHolder(view);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(JobViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final JobViewHolder wHolder = holder;

        //. you can get the item here
        JobModel jobModel = mJobList.get(position);

        holder.itemView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
           @Override
           public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

               return false;
           }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mJobList.size();
    }

    public class JobViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private View mItemView;
        private TextView mTextView;

        public JobViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mItemView = itemView;
            mTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view);

        }
   }

}

//. item_job_list.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="16sp" />        

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

use code like this

```
private RecyclerView mJobRecyclerView;
private JobListAdapter mJobListAdapter;

mJobListAdapter = new JobListAdapter(this);    

ArrayList<JobModel> jobList = new ArrayList<>();
//. add job
JobModel jobmodel = new JobModel();
jobList.add(jobmodel);

mJobListAdapter.setJobList(jobList);

mJobRecyclerView.setAdapter(mJobListAdapter);
```